# Wkhtmltopdf page margins inside layout

Tags: css, wkhtmltopdf, page-break

## Page margins/padding at page break

I'm trying to create a full-width two column layout pdf using [WkhtmlToPdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/). Normally not a problem at all. But in my case I have a sidebar with a background color. The issue that occurs is that the sidebar has it's own padding. When the page breaks the content breaks just as expected but without the padding. This is the expected behaviour (as seen in Example A). My question is how one could achieve this 'cloned' padding when breaking the content (desired result example B).

[image: Example of current situation and desired outcome]

After some searching I thought of the [box-decoration-break](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-decoration-break/) css property. But from what I could find only [Prince](https://www.princexml.com/) partially supports this property for `table` elements [Prince box-decoration-break example](https://www.princexml.com/samples/doc-latest/box-decoration-break.pdf) and from what it seems only for the `border` property.

But hey I could make that work, setting a transparent border for the top and bottom should give me the same effect as padding. But as you may know buying a Prince license is a pretty costly bussiness (at least for my current project it's not an option). And it's not the best solution with the need of extra html markup as only `table` elements are supported.